# Битва при чи під?

Tags: прийменники

На вікіпедії я зустрів два способи називати статті про битви біля міст.

Один варіант з *при*:

- [Битва при Кресі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%96)
- [Битва при Монте-Кассіно](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE)

Інший варіат з *під*:

- [Битва під Брієнном](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4_%D0%91%D1%80%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC)
- [Битва під Бродами](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Як правильно? За яким принципом обирати?

Answer (score 2):

ГРАК знаходить набагато більше випадків вживання "битва під":

[запит "битва під"](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac15&tab=advanced&keyword=%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4&attrs=word%2Clemma&viewmode=sen&attr_allpos=kw&refs_up=1&shorten_refs=0&itemsPerPage=500&structs=s%2Cg&refs=%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.mediaName%2C%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.locCode&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1&f_tab=advanced&c_itemsPerPage=500&c_customrange=1&operations=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22iquery%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%22%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22queryselector%22%3A%22iqueryrow%22%2C%22iquery%22%3A%22%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A1587%7D%5D) - 2923

[запит "битва при"](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac15&tab=advanced&keyword=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8&attrs=word%2Clemma&viewmode=sen&attr_allpos=kw&refs_up=1&shorten_refs=0&itemsPerPage=500&structs=s%2Cg&refs=%3Ddoc.date%2C%3Ddoc.mediaName%2C%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.locCode&default_attr=lemma&showresults=1&f_tab=advanced&c_itemsPerPage=500&c_customrange=1&operations=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22iquery%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%22%2C%22active%22%3Atrue%2C%22query%22%3A%7B%22queryselector%22%3A%22iqueryrow%22%2C%22iquery%22%3A%22%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A2366%7D%5D) - 565